# Construction of Lakes of Wada

Tags: general-topology

At each step of the construction of [Lakes of Wada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada) we extend a lake (an open set in the open unit square) so that no point of the land (the complement of all the lakes) is farther than a given small positive number (depending on the step) from the lake and the interior of the remaining land stays connected.

How can it be rigorously shown that this kind of extended lake exists?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know more about the Lakes of Wada you can refer research articles, but here is what I found in Mathoverflow

Just refer the link,it contains various nice links -

http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/24903/algorithms-for-the-lakes-of-wada

If the link doesnot open,we can try the following links-

1)http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-coudene.pdf

2)http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/brouwer.shtml

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the value of this answer.

Comment: The link to the article given on the MathOverflow page is broken, but this link works: http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-coudene.pdf

Comment: @JohnGowers, don't know why but the link opens in my system,and in the  page this link is also included.

Comment: @BAYMAX I edited it on the MathOverflow answer.

Comment: Ok,nice work ! still I have added the further links one will face while going deep through the pages! @JohnGowers